# Crontab -l empty but tasks are running

Tags: cron

I set up a cronjob some time ago that is working well. It does a mysqldump every day at 20:00.
This is the syslog output:

```
Nov 03 20:00:01 server CRON[124238]: (user) CMD (mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/home/user/.my.cnf" --all-databases -u user > /home/user/Dropbox/mysql-backup.sql
```

**The issue is that if I do `crontab -l` I get `no crontab for user` and `sudo crontab -l` -> `no crontab for root`**

I looked in:

```
    /etc/crontab    
    /etc/cron.hourly/
    /etc/cron.d/
    /etc/cron.daily/
    /etc/cron.hourly/
    /etc/cron.monthly/
    /etc/cron.weekly/
```

And I cannot find the task.

The `/etc/crontab/` is the default one:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Is there any way I can find where I set up the cronjob?

Comment: Please, check directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` also.

Comment: Seems empty too.